# Blocking queue with task

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Problem:
I have filesystem where files appear and i want to upload them over WCF. What i want is to limit maximum number of parallelism to some *ThreadMaxConcurrency*

Idea is to utilize Producer-Consumer pattern in blockingQueue. Producing part is - UploadNewFile,CreateFolder etc...

What i am blind of is that consumer part. 
Also what i dont know is to some kind of... delay single task - 
For an example - DONT upload new files before FolderWasCreated for them.

I am using .NET 4.5 and i dont know how to utilize  BlockingQueue and how to properly monitor if there is task and how to monitor and how to postpone some task until another one completes (enqueue them to the end again would work i guess).

Comment: It seems there is a lot about this problem you don't know. You should focus on each element individually, posting a _specific_ question for each part you are having difficulty with. There are a lot of ways to go about solving the broader problem here, but to go into detail on the whole problem in a single answer would be too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a framework that does all that for you. You create an `AcionBlock`, give it a delegate and set it's `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

It should look similar to this:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<string>(folderName => 
{
    UploadFolder(folderName);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 });

foreach (var folderName in GetFolderNames())
{
    block.Post(folderName);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

Comment: well i knew there will be a library exactly for that purpose. I my own implementation and get to much of problems with that. Thanks this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Is there a simple way how to postpone a task untill another one is finished ? (dont upload files untill folder for them is created)

Comment: @LightCZ Just put everything inside `UploadFolder` and it will happen one after the other.